# JQuery Animate() slide div up from bottom of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate

Hopefully simple  but tried implementing answers from other SO questions to no avail.

I have a div I that I want to slide up from the bottom of the page when the document loads. However, I just cant seem to get the JQuery working. Here is what I have:

```
#content {
    width: 640px;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top: 2000px;
}

$(function(){

$('#content').animate({MarginTop: '50px',} 1000);

});
```

Basically, I just want to shrink the `margin-top` distance when the page loads.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try:

```
$('#content').animate({'margin-top': '50px'}, 1000);
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MvQsT/1/)

Comment: Ah yep - got it working now! Just the comma was on the wrong side of your } above (I have fixed it now) Thanks heaps!